# Rating system for multiple models in Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I need suggestion for rating system implementation. I have Blogs, Discussions, Comments in my system, so each member can make +1 to current blog post or discussion entry, comment etc. I know  that there is acts_as_ratable, but this is no what I need.

Any suggestions, what can I use to keep my code DRY?

P.S - I know it can be handled using polymorphic associations, but I'm searching for basic solution to integrate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, and sorry I misunderstood your question on my first attempt.  Actually, I am still not sure what you're looking for.  Examples? Gems?  What is it about acts_as_ratable that is unsuitable?  A little more detail about requirements would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect case for Rails' polymorphic associations -- several different types are "ratable".

Good doc on this here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

And great screencast here:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

Comment: I have already implemented a lot of functionality base on polymorphic associations. I'm just searching for solution to integrate.